# How to change travel mode in Mapquest as like in google as DRIVING ,WALKING?

Tags: api, mapquest

I have got the code for generating a map and waypoints from Mapquest. But not getting enough idea to change the travel mode as Driving or walking. Please help me find a solution.

Comment: The working fiddle is :
  http://jsfiddle.net/TechmazeSolution/zo7eqtzj/

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more detail or a code sample?

If you're using the JavaScript Maps API, [this might be helpful](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/sdk/javascript/v7.2/routing#routenarrative).  Take a look at the options on this example.  To change the travel mode, you'll want to look at the routeType parameter.  Your choices are: fastest, shortest, pedestrian, multimodal, and bicycle.

If you're using the Routing Plugin for Leaflet, [this might be helpful](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/plugins/leaflet/v1.0/routing#options).  You can use the same options for routeType as mentioned above.

Comment: The working fiddle is : jsfiddle.net/TechmazeSolution/zo7eqtzj  this code takes 20-30secs to load the waypoints. Please help to find a solution.